# BASH - Delete lines and replace them by blank lines

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have a text file and I would like to delete some lines **and** replace them by blank ones.
Example: If I have this file:

> 1. Off through the new day's mist I run
> 2. Off from the new day's mist
> 3. I have come
> 4. I hunt

I would like this output:

> 1. Off through the new day's mist I run
> 2. 
> 3. 
> 4. I hunt

I already tried this command but there is no blank lines:

`sed -i "$deb,$end"'d' body.txt` (where $deb and $end are the number of the lines)

Do you have any clue on how to get this output format using bash, sed or awk? (I cannot use Perl)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of deleting, just replace the line with empty value:

```
sed -i "${deb},${end}s/.*//" body.txt
```

Comment: Works great, thank you!
I used this format to use it inside a bash script (sorry I did not mention that in my first post)
`sed -i "$deb,$end"'s/.*//' body.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Try this awk command,

```
awk -v var1=2 -v var2=3 'NR==var1{gsub (/.*/,"")} NR==var2{gsub (/.*/,"")}1' file
```

Example:

```
$ awk -v var1=2 -v var2=3 'NR==var1{gsub (/.*/,"")} NR==var2{gsub (/.*/,"")}1' rr.txt
        Off through the new day's mist I run


        I hunt
```

OR

```
$ awk -v var1=$deb -v var2=$end 'NR==var1{gsub (/.*/,"")} NR==var2{gsub (/.*/,"")}1' rr.txt
        Off through the new day's mist I run


        I hunt
```

Comment: Try `NR<var1 || NR>var2 { print }`.

Comment: @Kaz op want the deleted lines also, take a look at the expected output.

Comment: For the blank lines, you just need: `NR>=var1 && NR <=var2 { print "" }`